# Using datatable with MVC 3 and WebGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am writing my first internet application with MVC 3 but I'm having issues with getting the data to bind to the Webgrid.  I am pulling the data using a stored procedure and storing it in a datatable in the model.  I can't bind directly using the datatable so I am converting it to an EnumerableRowCollection, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've seen examples where they list out each field in the model and I think that is a ridiculously way to have to do this.  Also, the field returned for this report or dynamic based on what they have chosen to see and the order they see it in.

In my model:

```
namespace ShipStatReportsModels.Models
{
    public class ShipStatData
    {
        public EnumerableRowCollection GetReportData()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection _SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADONETHorizoninetuser"]))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UP_ShipStatReports_DataPresentation", _SqlConnection))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
                        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact_id", 43135);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact_Server_ID", 17);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Report_Id", 1);

                        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }          

            return dt.AsEnumerable();
        }

    }
}
```

In my collection:

```
public ActionResult Reports()
{
    ShipStatData modelObject = new ShipStatData();
    EnumerableRowCollection resultSet = modelObject.GetReportData();

    return View(resultSet);
}
```

In my view:

```
@{

    ViewBag.Title = "Reports";
}
@model ShipStatReportsModels.Models.ShipStatData

@{
    var Grid = new WebGrid(@Model);
}


<h2>Reports</h2>

<div>
@Grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt"
    )
)
</div>
```

But I get the following error:

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.WebGrid(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, string, int, bool, bool, string, string, string, string, string, string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't use EF or another ORM?  It would make your life much easier.

Comment: How is EF easier?  With standard asp.net, in one statement I could bind the datatable to a gridview and see the data.  I am not looking to do any insert, update, delete.  I also don't see the purpose of defining every column especially when there are over 30 and the columns returned will be dynamic.

Comment: Because then you won't need to use the data table as your model or map between the data table and some other domain object.

Comment: How is mapping or binding from a data table a bad thing?  Do you really want to do things like this?

Comment: `public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }        
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }        
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: I agree with user1130587. EF seems like a pretty heavy artillery for this simple task.

Comment: I doubt that the only thing this application does is attempt to display a data table in an MVC view.  It sounds like you are missing a domain model, etc though so it may be a tall order as it looks like you are missing SoC, etc.

Comment: The entire project is part of much larger solution.  It's purpose is to mainly display several reports derived from stored procedure calls.  Not anything complex, but we thought we'd use MVC for it to get familiar.  Well so far it is not going very well.